# OpenCv input samples must be floating-point matrix ERROR

Tags: c++, opencv, android-ndk, machine-learning

Hi I am using this code for find_nearest

```
resize(ROI, tmp1, Size(10, 15), 0, 0, INTER_LINEAR);
tmp1.convertTo(tmp2, CV_32FC1);
float p = knn.find_nearest(tmp2.reshape(1, 1), 1);
```

but I receive `Input Samples must be floating-point matrix`

Why??

Comment: Where did you define `tmp2`?

Answer (score 1):

I have the sam error but I try to solve it by convert matrix (temp2) to 1D

Answer (score 0):

Check the matrix dimensions

I managed to solve the issue by having the sample matrix (`tmp2` in your case) transposed. Besides having the elements float, it is supposed to have the dimensions right (as it says in the exception message):  `(<num_samples>x<var_count>))`